# 404 Not Found when hard reload the page in react js with react build

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am getting Not Found error when i am hard reloading the page but it works fine i do normal reload with build .Here is my Router tag. **I did not use createBrowserHistory. Is it the issue?**

```
<Router basename={process.env.PUBLIC_URL}>
           <Switch >
          <div >
            <Navbar />
            <Route exact path="/" component={HomeComponent} />
            <Route exact path="/score/:id" component={ScoreComponent} />
            <Route exact path="/login" component={LoginComponent} />
            <Route exact path="/forgotPassword" component={ForgotPasswordComponent} />
          </div> 
          </Switch >
      </Router>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**I resolve this issue by below .htaccess code**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
  RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: such a helpful answer, I was looking for this solution since so long. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

You get the 404 because the router doesn't figure out which path to choose. What if you use the `Redirect` tag as a catch all other cases kind of thing?

Comment: i think this is not issue. the error is given by Apache is here . 

Not Found

The requested URL /index.html was not found on this server.

Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80